# Find the time when tangential acceleration is equal to radial acceleration

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, acceleration, rotational-kinematics

> A particle begins to move along a circular path of radius R with a constant magnitude tangential acceleration of $a_t$. After time $t$ it's the centripetal acceleration is equal in magnitude to tangential acceleration. Find $t$?

**My Attempt:**

$$a_t = \frac{dv}{dt}$$

$$a_r = \frac{v^2}{R}$$

Where,
$R =$ Radius of the circle
$a_r = $ Radial acceleration of the circle

(As given in the question)

$$a_t = a_r$$

$$\frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{v^2}{R}$$

I think integrating will give us the $t$, but what should be the limits?

Integrating from $t=0$ and $v=0$ doesn't work well. It just gives infinity.

If my way doesn't work, then how do I approach this problem?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that this site is not a place to obtain solutions to worked problems. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/25301) and [this Meta post for "check my work problems"](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/25301).

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to treat your final equation as a differential equation you need to solve. That equation is only going to be valid at one instant in time, whereas if you integrate it you will be assuming it holds at all times, and hence you won't have a constant $a_t$. Really what you have for a single time $T$ is
$$a_t(T)=a_r(T)$$
$$\left. \frac{\text dv}{\text dt}\right|_{t=T}=\frac{\left(v(T)\right)^2}{R}$$

You need to determine what $v(t)$ will be based on $\dot v=a_t$ and then it should be fairly easy from there. I'll leave the rest for you to do.

Answer (score -1):

You know that $a_r=\frac{v^2}{R}$ and that $v = a_tt$ (since the particle starts from rest and accelerates with constants tangential acceleration). So

$a_r=\frac{a_t^2t^2}{R}$

At the instant when $a_r=a_t$ then

$a_t=\frac{a_t^2t^2}{R}$

Now you just have to solve to find $t$.